# 100+ buildtime issues on fresh react-native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

When building a react-native app, the build succeeds, but Xcode logs more than 100 issues in the buildtime log. Is this normal?

[image: Screenshot of Xcode log]

All I did was:

1. Installed Xcode (9.2)
2. brew install node (9.9.0)
3. brew install watchman (4.9.0)
4. npm install -g react-native-cli (2.0.1)
5. cd ~/Development && react-native init Test
6. Open ios/Test.xcodeproj and hit the Run button (iPhone 8 simulator)

Again - the build succeeds. But all the issues in the logs concerns me and I was not able to find others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Those warnings are not a big issue. The various RCT projects were created with an older version of Xcode. Xcode is suggesting you update the projects to Xcode's recommended settings.

To update to the recommended settings, select one of the Update to recommended settings warnings shown in your screenshot. A sheet will open. Click the Perform Changes button to update the project settings.