# xcode react-native app build fails - how do I find the reason?

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a React-Native app (includes native code) that I built so far only for android and I would like to build on iOS.

I am using Xcode 10.1. I followed the instructions in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios/ and the build failed when I ran `react-native run-ios`

I read that it is better to run the build in Xcode, since it will be easier to see, from build logs, the reason for the failure.

Here is how the build screen looks after the failure. Where should I look for the reason of the failure? (e.g in the 'React' issues? Anywhere else?)
 Is the message `"Signing for <app> requires a development team"` indicating the reason of the failure? All the other errors are marked with a yellow '!' (I assume that this indicates a warning, not a fatal error), this is the only one with a red '!' mark...

And another question: if I want to start fresh, how do I clear the above log? I tried to execute product->clean, but this fails, too.

[image: Build failure screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Xcode issue - and should be an easy one to resolve. Try clicking the "Add Account" button. If you have set up a team, you should see it there, and you can add it. If not, go to the Xcode tab, then Preferences > Accounts and make sure you are logged in with your Apple ID.

As for the 188 warnings, [this might help explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436887/100-buildtime-issues-on-fresh-react-native-project)

To get rid of the warning messages and back to your folder structure, click the folder icon in the top left corner of the screen